# Problemas ao trabalhar com datas no banco de dados usando um maskedtextbox no formato dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, microsoft-access, oledb

Estou usando um MaskedTextBox na cultura pt-BR pra forçar o usuário a preencher a data no formato correto (dd/MM/yyyy). Retiro a string do MaskedTextBox  para inserir  no banco de dados e  registrar uma informação  contendo a data desta informação. Meu intuito é que o usuário possa além de registrar algumas informações, possa também realizar uma pesquisa por período de tempo filtrando as datas através de dois MounthCalendar.

O problema é que aparentemente as informações estão sendo registradas no formato MM/dd/yyyy e quando realizo a pesquisa por período, o banco de dados retorna as datas com os meses invertidos com as datas.

Por exemplo, se eu registro um evento chamado de "Calibração" com a data 02/03/2016 (02 de março de 2016) , no banco de dados o registro fica como 03 de fevereiro de 2016. E se eu fizer uma pesquisa no período de 01 de março de 2016 a 31 de março de 2016, o evento de "Calibração" não aparece nos resultados. Mas, se fizer a pesquisa no período entre 01 e 29 de fevereiro de 2016 o evento aparece como se estivesse registrado no dia 03 de fevereiro.

Não sei se estou enganado, mas creio que o problema esteja acontecendo na hora de inserir no banco de dados, estou tentando converter a string que é digitada no MaskedTextBox para o formato MM/dd/yyyy mas não estou conseguindo.

Já tentei usar o DateTime.ParseExact mas surge o erro : "Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido."

```
string dataDoFat = mskData.Text;
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles none = new System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles();
IFormatProvider format = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dtime = DateTime.ParseExact(dataDoFat, "MM/dd/yyyy",format);
```

O código que uso para inserir os registros no banco de dados é este:

```
            Conexao ca = new Conexao();
            string sql = "";
            sql += " Insert Into SisIndice (FAT, nSerie, idDefeito, DataFat) ";
            sql += " Values ( ";
            sql += " " + txtFat.Text + ", ";
            sql += " '" + txtnSerie.Text + "', ";
            sql += " " + cboDefeito.SelectedValue + ", ";
            sql += " #" + mskData.Text  + "# ";
            sql += " ) ";
            ca.Conectar();
            OleDbCommand cd = new OleDbCommand(sql, ca.cx);
            try
            {
                cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorrência registrada.");
            }
            catch (OleDbException x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + x.Message);
            }
            ca.Desconectar();
            LimparCampos();
```

E o que uso para ler os registros do banco de dados no período de tempo escolhido pelo usuário é este:

```
        string DataInicio = mcInicio.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string DataFim = mcFim.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        Conexao ca = new Conexao();
        string sql = "";
        sql += " Select ";
        sql += " s.idProduto, s.FAT, s.nSerie, d.Defeito, s.DataFat ";
        sql += " From ";
        sql += " (SisIndice s INNER JOIN ";
        sql += " Defeitos d ON s.idDefeito = d.idDefeito) ";
        sql += " WHERE(((s.DataFat) BETWEEN ";
        sql += " #" + DataInicio + "# ";
        sql += " and ";
        sql += " #" + DataFim + "#)) ";
        ca.Conectar();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "SisIndice");

        dgvTestGraf.DataSource = ds.Tables["SisIndice"];
        ca.Desconectar();
```

Realmente a solução é converter o formato da data inserida no banco de dados? Qual é a melhor maneira para se fazer isso?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leandro,

Provavelmente ele está invertendo o dia e mês na hora de inserir.

A melhor maneira de se trabalhar com data é enviar o parâmetro no seu command.

```
Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("nome","valor"));
```

Usando dessa forma, o próprio OleDb fará a conversão para o formato correto.

Além do código ficar mais seguro evitando SQL Injection.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Marcelo!!!